# Angular controller in directive cause strict di error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use the ng-strict-di mod in my app. It works for all my DI, except when I try to use a controller in a directive. FYI I use the John Papa style guide to format my code.

Here is my directive :

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.mymodule')
        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

    myDirective.$inject = [];

    function  myDirective() {
        var directive = {
            bindToController: true,
            controller: MyDirectiveCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data:'='
            },   
            templateUrl: 'my-directive-template.html',  
        };
        return directive;

        MyDirectiveCtrl.$inject = ['ServiceSvc'];
        function MyDirectiveCtrl(ServiceSvc) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.foo = foo;

            function foo() {
                ServiceSvc.bar();
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

So I inject explicitly my `ServiceSvc` in my `MyDirectiveCtrl` but in my Chrom console I've got an error about strict DI :

```
Error: [$injector:strictdi] MyDirectiveCtrl is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/strictdi?p0=MyDirectiveCtrl 
    at vendor.js:10
    at Function.annotate [as $$annotate] (vendor.js:209)
    at Object.invoke (vendor.js:233)
    at extend.instance (vendor.js:443)
    at nodeLinkFn (vendor.js:374)
    at vendor.js:397
    at processQueue (vendor.js:703)
    at vendor.js:704
    at Scope.$eval (vendor.js:748)
    at Scope.$digest (vendor.js:743)
```

Any idea why i get this error ?

Comment: Actually this looks like the error is about `NotificationListCtrl`. Take a look at the URL.

Comment: Yes it was because for this post I change the real name  `NotificationListCtrl` into `MyDirectiveCtrl`. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to use the controller defined in your directive outside, as below

```
 angular
        .module('app.mymodule')
        .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = [];

function  kissNotificationList() {
    var directive = {
        bindToController: true,
        controller: MyDirectiveCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data:'='
        },   
        templateUrl: 'my-directive-template.html',  
    };
    return directive;


}

//direcitves controller

 MyDirectiveCtrl.$inject = ['ServiceSvc'];

 function MyDirectiveCtrl(ServiceSvc) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.foo = foo;

        function foo() {
            ServiceSvc.bar();
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I don't understand why my way doesn't work. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: $inject never gets run , as the directive initialized and returned  immediately.

Comment: @Tako  no problem , i'm glad to help :)